# How do I check if an instance class is equal to a variable inside the class?

Tags: c#, instance

How do I check if an instance class is equal to a variable inside the class?

```
public class ChainType
{
    public ChainType none;
    public ChainType unknown;
    public ChainType horizontal;
    public ChainType vertical;
    public ChainType centerCross;
    public ChainType leftTopCornerCross;
    public ChainType rightTopCornerCross;
    public ChainType leftBottomCornerCross;
    public ChainType rightBottomCornerCross;
}

public class aClass{
    ChainType chainType = new ChainType();

    someMethod(){
        chainType = getChainType(); // sets to chainType.horizontal

        if(chainType == ChainType.horizontal){..} // getting Error here about object reference to non-static class
    }
}
```

Comment: I reckon you are better off using `enum`s

Comment: I am trying to follow tip no. 36 here. http://devmag.org.za/2012/07/12/50-tips-for-working-with-unity-best-practices/

Comment: @user1555300 If something recommend classes over enums I'd think that's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tip actually addresses `enum`s, so let's forget about that.

There is a subtile difference between your code and the example. The class name is `Bullets`, plural. You 
should change your class name to `ChainTypes` and you should be fine.

```
public class ChainTypes
{
    public ChainType none;
    public ChainType unknown;
    public ChainType horizontal;
    public ChainType vertical;
    public ChainType centerCross;
    public ChainType leftTopCornerCross;
    public ChainType rightTopCornerCross;
    public ChainType leftBottomCornerCross;
    public ChainType rightBottomCornerCross;
}

ChainTypes types = new ChainTypes();
ChainType chaintype = getChainType();   
if (chainType == types.horizontal) {
}
```

I understand the reasoning, but this can be quite tricky in comparisons (the tip doesn't address the usages of the `Bullet`s. Comparison is done on references, so you will have to make `ChainTypes` static and make sure you always return the correct instance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this that way, you should add `static` modifier to fields in `ChainType`:

```
public class ChainType
{
    public static ChainType none;
    public static ChainType unknown;
    ...
    public static ChainType rightBottomCornerCross;
}
```

But I don't think it would solve your problem. It will compile but it won't work.

`chainType` is pointer and so are none, uknown, .... You can compare it your ways only if you assign to chainType one of none, unknown, ....

Enums should be betters:

```
public enum ChainType
{
    none,
    unknown,
    ...
}
```

There is no need to change your code after switching to enums.

EDIT ("I am trying to follow tip no. 36 here. devmag.org.za/2012/07/12/")

You get this wrong way. Tip 36 says that you should have separate variables for Bullets instead of using array:

```
Bullet bulletTypeA
Bullet bulletTypeB
...
```

instead of

```
Bullet[] bullets;
bullets[BulletType.A]
```

Comment: This would result in a "variable not initialised" warning.

Comment: Your middle part makes no sense.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance `ChainType ct = ChainType.none`. `ct == ChainType.none` would work, because ct is pointing to the same memory where ChainType.none is pointing.

Answer (score 0):

First: you have to define them static:

```
public class ChainType
{
    public static ChainType none; //STATIC !!
    ... 
}
```

so you can access to them like `ChainType.horizontal`.

Second: pay attention on a fact, that writing the code like

```
if(chainType == ChainType.horizontal){..}
```

copares *references* of this 2 isntances, and ***not*** thier content. 
If this is what you expect, just go ahead with the first fix, if not, you have to define custom equality comparer for your type too.

Answer (score 0):

You should use enumerations for this purposes:

```
public enum ChainType
{
    none,
    unknown,
    horizontal,
    vertical,
    centerCross,
    leftTopCornerCross,
    rightTopCornerCross,
    leftBottomCornerCross,
    rightBottomCornerCross
}

public class aClass{
    ChainType chainType = ChainType.horizontal;

    someMethod(){

        if(chainType == ChainType.horizontal){..} 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best approach. If you are using these classes to define what something is then I would recommend an enum.

If they are required in some kind of inheritance structure then you should be comparing GetType()'s or typeof(object).

Lastly if you need to test that two objects are the same (as in the same actual thing in your program) then you are missing an initialisation of each of those instance variables and your getChainType should return one of those instances.

Answer (score 0):

All answer are correct that shouting to use enums (though it is best practice)but let see error, error is self explanatory. You are directly accessing non static property of a Class(Class not its object) Insead you can try chainType.horizontal (here chainType is object of ChainType class).